# Python3: Can't get child class to inherit parent class method properly

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

This feels like a stupid bug that I'm going to kick myself over but I feel like I've tried everything.

Basically, when I try to access a parent method from the child it says I'm missing the destination argument:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remote_submission_rand.py", line 113, in <module>
    XYZ.rsyncFile(source, outfiles)
TypeError: rsyncFile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'destination'
```

This obviously sounds like I'm doing something wrong with self when organising the inheritance but I've played around for hours and can't get something that works. Any advice would be much apreciated?

Please see parent and child classes below:

Child class:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import subprocess
import sys
class Connection(metaclass=ABCMeta):
        """This is an abstract class that all cluster classes inherit from.""" 
        def __init__(self, cluster_user_name, ssh_config_alias, path_to_key):
                """In order to initiate this class the user must have their ssh config file set up to have their cluster connection as an alias."""
                self.user_name = cluster_user_name 
                self.ssh_config_alias = ssh_config_alias
                self.path_to_key = path_to_key
                # add the ssh key so that if there's a password then the user can enter it now
                ssh_add_cmd = "eval `ssh-agent -s`;ssh-add " + self.path_to_key
                subprocess.check_output(ssh_add_cmd, shell=True)
                self.job_numbers_to_wait_for = []

        # instance methods
        def rsyncFile(self, source, destination, rsync_flags = "-aP"):
                rsync_cmd = ["rsync", rsync_flags, source, self.ssh_config_alias + ":" + destination]
                exit_code = self.sendCommand(rsync_cmd)                                                                                                                  
                return exit_code
```

Parent class:

```
from base_connection import Connection
import subprocess
class XYZ(Connection):
        def __init__(self, cluster_user_name, ssh_config_alias, path_to_key):
                Connection.__init__(self, cluster_user_name, ssh_config_alias, path_to_key)

        #instance methhods
        def rsyncFile(self, source, destination, rsync_flags = "-aP"):
                super(XYZ, self).rsyncFile(source, destination, rsync_flags)

                return
```

Use of classes:

```
from connections import XYZ

outfiles = '/path/to/outfiles'
source_path = '/path/a_file.list'

XYZ.rsyncFile(source_path, outfiles)
```

ADDITION:
I also tried with no rsyncFile function in the XYZ class at all and got exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I realised I just did something really stupid (must have needed some sleep!).

What happened was I forgot to actual create an instance of the class! I also forgot to declare self in a couple of functions which led to some previous calls working which in turn led me astray deugging. Anyway the solution is instead of:

```
from connections import XYZ

outfiles = '/path/to/outfiles'
source_path = '/path/a_file.list'

XYZ.rsyncFile(source_path, outfiles)
```

We should have:

```
from connections import XYZ

outfiles = '/path/to/outfiles'
source_path = '/path/a_file.list'
XYZ_inputs = stuff

XYZ_conn = XYZ(XYZ_inputs)
XYZ_conn.rsyncFile(source_path, outfiles)
```